# Watson-Nevanlinna theorem for $e^{-1/z}$

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, divergent-series, summation-method

I am currently trying to understand Watson-Nevanlinna (WN) theorem, which gives sufficent conditions for a function $f(z)$ to be equal to the Borel sum of its asymptotic expansion as $z\to0$.

The theorem is stated as follows.

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the circle $C_R=\{z:\mathrm{Re}(z^{-1})>R^{-1}\}$, $R>0$, and let $f(z)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$ be its asymptotic expansion as  $z\to 0$. If the remainder after summing $N-1$ terms satisfies

$$
\vert R_N(z)\vert\leq A\sigma^N N! |z|^N,\quad A>0,\,{}\sigma>0,
$$

uniformly in $N$ and $z\in C_R$, then:

- $B(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n/n!$ converges in $S_\sigma=\{t:\mathrm{dist}(t,\mathbb{R}^+)<1/\sigma\}$, and
- $f(z)$ equals the convergent integral $f(z)=(1/z)\int_0^\infty e^{-tz}B(t)\mathrm{d}t$ for any $z\in C_R$.

However, from reading some reviews on asymptotic expansions, I was under the impression that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$ is asymptotic to $f(z)$ as $z\to0$ along paths in the $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$ part of the complex plane of $z$ (where the circle $C_R$ is contained), then it is also asymptotic to $f(z)+e^{-1/z}$, as $e^{-1/z}$ has an expansion in powers of $z$ that vanishes at all orders. Due to this, I was taking $e^{-1/z}$ as some sort of lower boundary in the accuracy in obtaining a function $f(z)$ from its asymptotic expansion as $z\to0$ in powers of $z$.

WN theorem seems to suggest that, provided the conditions on $f(z)$ are satisfied, one can recover $f(z)$ exactly from the asymptotic expansion, and I am having trouble understanding that. Indeed, the function $e^{-1/z}$ itself seems to satisfy the conditions of the theorem, but its Borel transform $B(t)$ is identically zero and so is the integral. The theorem then would ensure $e^{-1/z}=0$ in $C_R$, which is not true.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: for further clarification. The reviews and books on asymptotic expansions that I have been reading emphasize the fact that the function $e^{-1/z}$ has, for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$, the following asymptotic expansion as $z$ tends to $0$ and with respect to the sequence $\{z^n\}^\infty_{n=0}$: $$e^{-1/z}\sim 0+0\cdot z^2+0\cdot z^3+...$$
Due to this, they remark that more than one function can have the same asymptotic expansion, and the example for asymptotic expansions as $z$ tends to $0$ in the $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$ part of the complex plane and with respect to the sequence $\{z^n\}^\infty_{n=0}$ are the functions $f(z)$ and $f(z)+e^{-1/z}$.
My suprise comes when [Watsons theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation#:%7E:text=Uniqueness%20theorems,-There%20are%20always&text=Watson%27s%20theorem%20and%20Carleman%27s%20theorem,possible%20sum%20of%20the%20series.) or Watson-Nevanlinna theorem state conditions under which an asymptotic power series at $z=0$ equals a function, as I fail to see why it wouldn't be possible to add $e^{-1/z}$ terms to obtain a different function with the same asymptotic expansion.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “its asymptotic expansion as $z\mapsto0$”. It would still be problematic if $\mapsto$ were amended to $\to$: For example, $f:z\mapsto1/z$ is analytic in $C_R$ but has no power-series expansion of the form you stated that is valid arbitrarily near the origin. In addition to clarifying what is meant here, some further condition is needed: at least the boundedness of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ (in $C_R$) is required.

Comment: @JohnBentin By "as $z\mapsto 0$" I only mean "as $z$ tends to $0$ along paths in $C_R$". Perhaps the standard notation is $ z\rightarrow 0$; I can fix my question if that is the case. In any case, I don't understand why some further condition is needed: I merely stated the theorem as it can be found in "An improvment on Watson's theorem on Borel summability", by A.D. Sokal (I couldn't find an open source for this paper, otherwise I would have posted it).

Comment: @JohnBentin  My concern is that this theorem (or, by that matter, the original theorem by Watson that can be found in the Borel summation page of Wikipedia) seems to ensure that, provided some conditions are satisfied, the Borel sum of an asymptotic power series equals a function $f(z)$. Since one can add terms of the form $e^{1/z}$ to $f(z)$ and still get the same asymptotic power expansion, I don't see how one can claim the equality.

Comment: the link you provide about Watson's theorem explains fairly clearly (paragraph below Carleman's theorem) why $e^{-1/z}$ is not a counterexample since one needs the respective conditions to hold for $|\arg z| <\pi/2+\epsilon$ and in the $e^{-1/z}$ case, they hold only for $|\arg z| \le \pi/2$

Comment: @Conrad True, but the WN theorem only demands $z\in C_R$. Since $C_R$ is contained in the $\mathrm{Re}z>0$ part of the complex plane, $e^{-1/z}$ is analytic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $w:=1/z$, you have to verify $\left| {w^N {\rm e}^{ - w} } \right| \le A\sigma ^N N!$ for all $N\geq 1$ and $\operatorname{Re} (w) > r: = R^{ - 1}$, with some positive $R$, $A$ and $\sigma$. But taking $w = 2r + \mathrm{i}T$ (note that $\operatorname{Re} (w) =2r > r$)
$$
\left| {w^N {\rm e}^{ - w} } \right| = \left| {(2r + \mathrm{i}T)^N } \right|{\rm e}^{ - 2r}  \ge T^N {\rm e}^{ - 2r},
$$ which can be arbitrarily large if $T$ is large enough.

Comment: Thanks! While I see from your answer that $\vert w^N e^{-w}\vert$ does not satisfy the bounding condition, there is still one thing I don't understand: should't one be checking this condition for the aymptotic series? My reasoning was that if $e^{-1/z}\sim 0+0\cdot z+...$ as $z\rightarrow0$ along paths in $C_R$, then the remainder is zero at all orders and obviusly satisfy the bounding condition.

Comment: The remainder $R_N(z)$ after $N$ terms is defined by $R_N(z):=e^{-1/z}-(0+0\cdot z+\ldots +0\cdot z^{N-1})=e^{-1/z}$ which is non-zero.

Comment: You're absolutely right; thanks for the clarification.